# How to fill the page and adjust text position according to resize

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I'm new to xaml and Windows 10 Gui programming. I want to design a page with a TextBlock, a ListBox and a Button, all centered in the page. I want the TextBlock and the button always reside at the top and bottom of the page no matter how users resize the window. The ListBox should stretch itself to fill the gap between TextBlock and ListBox automatically. I have tried set VerticalAlignment to different value, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<Page
x:Class="FirstWin10.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FirstWin10"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,20,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Run Text="Unkown Screen Name"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run/>
    </TextBlock>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="450" MinHeight="178" Margin="50,20,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox />
            <TextBox Text="ListBox Item #1" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox />
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="ListBox Item #2"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox />
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="ListBox Item #3"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox />
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="ListBox Item #4"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,20,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a `Grid` with three rows. The first and last rows are auto stretched to the size of the `TextBlock` and `Button`; the middle row takes the rest of the space.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> <!-- Grid.Row="0" can be removed as it's the default -->
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin. This is what I want.

Comment: a side question, how could make the TextBox stretch according to the window resize? Same solution using Grid?

Comment: It should auto-stretch. But if you put it inside a ListBox, you will need to override its ItemContainerStyle. Try googling, there's many answers on SO that tells you how to do it.